# checkbox status "checked" by default problem

Tags: php

I have a page with search form on it and table with search results below. In search form i have checkbox "Search in this category". What i'm doing to check it by default :

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['inthiscat'])){
    $_SESSION['inthiscat'] = 'on' ;
    $checked = 'checked';
}
$_GET['inthiscat'] = $_SESSION['inthiscat'];
```

checkbox code : INPUT type="checkbox" name="inthiscat"`<?=$checked?>`.
Link to next page of results index.php?inthiscat=$_GET['inthiscat'].
So the problem is when i uncheck "Search in this category" its still checked when i going to next page of results. How to fix it and what i'm doing wrong? Session startet of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, do you really need SESSION variables for this?  If you want box to be *checked* when GET parameter is not specified, you do not need SESSIONs at all.

Assuming you want to preserve the behaviour in case someone removes the GET parameter:

```
<?php
session_start();
//......
//......
$checked='checked';
if(isset($_REQUEST['inthiscat'])) {
   // Form input and url GET parameters take precedence
   if($_REQUEST['inthiscat'] != 'checked') { $checked = ''; };
} else if(isset($_SESSION['inthiscat'])) { 
   // Next, use session variable if it exists
   if($_SESSION['inthiscat'] != 'checked') { $checked = ''; };
};
$_SESSION['inthiscat']=$checked;
?>
```

Note:

1) Assigning values to GET array is not a good practice.

2) I assume you are using correct syntax for your FORM submit.

3) IMO, you could remove the SESSION variable as you are explicitly passing as GET parameter in the subsequent urls. Or dont use the GET parameter in urls.

Comment: The point is that i need "checked" when page loaded 1st time. and then if checked status unset, it must be unset on the next page. I don't know how to do this. I can add more code if it needed.

Comment: JP19, you're not storing the new data in the session this way. Also Why are you assigning a value to $_GET? As in `$_GET['inthiscat'] = $_SESSION['inthiscat'];`.

Comment: edited answer for the GET. As far as SESSION variable was concerned, I assumed OP only wanted to track first visit, and default behaviour if GET parameter was not specified.

Comment: One more thing, 1,2,3... number of pages with results and links on it look like "index.php?inthiscat=on" or "index.php?inthiscat=" and this links are formed when page loaded and if i unset checked status they are still have inthiscat=on. how can i change links when checkbox status changed?

Comment: How are you "unsetting the checked status"? The links will automatically be changed if you are properly using the `$checked` variable. Try refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is: when you uncheck the checkbox and go to the next page, `$_SESSION['inthiscat']` will still be unset - where did you change it?

Here is the code:

```
if (isset($_GET['inthiscat'])) {
    $_SESSION['inthiscat'] = $_GET['inthiscat'];
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['inthiscat'])) {
    $checked = 'checked';
} else {
    if ($_SESSION['inthiscat'] == 'on') {
       $checked = 'checked';
    } else {
       $cheked = '';
    }
}
```

Assuming this HTML: `<INPUT type="checkbox" name="inthiscat" checked="<?=$checked?>" value="on" />`

So what it does is:

1. Looks for the GET data and, if there is, assigns it (can be 'on' or '') to the SESSION;
2. If there is no SESSION (that means, no GET as well) it's the first page of that kind the user visits, so checked;
3. If there is a SESSION for inthiscat, it means it's not the first page and GET data has been assigned to the SESSION. So, if it's `on`, it displays the mark; else, it does not.